# Using UTF8 in Postgresql ODBC connection

Tags: c++, postgresql, winapi, odbc

I'm trying to insert some UTF-8 strings into PostgreSQL database. I'm using Visual C++ and MFC (this bit probably not important) and a project setting "Use Multi-Byte Character Set" (trying to switch database in an old legacy app). So when I execute some INSERT command with some text in Cyrillic "АБВГ" I expect to see this text in database, but I'm seeing this instead (in DBeaver): "ÐÐ‘Ð’Ð“". I insert this text by converting the string "\xC0\xC1\xC2\xC3" from code page 1251 to CP_UTF8.

When I change the system setting "Language for non-Unicode programs" from English to some Cyrillic, like Russian, the text that is actually inserted is no longer "ÐÐ‘Ð’Ð“", but "РђР‘Р’Р“". Postgres ODBC driver apparently uses CP_ACP to interpret my multi-byte strings. Indeed, if I now try to insert "\xC0\xC1\xC2\xC3" directly (without conversion to UTF-8), I do see "АБВГ" in database. But I need to insert UTF-8 strings, not a subset from a code page.

How do I instruct the Postgres ODBC driver to interpret my strings as UTF-8, and ignore the "Language for non-Unicode programs" system setting?

In PSQL console both `server_encoding` and `client_encoding` are set to `UTF8`.

Comment: For cp 1252 your string `ÐÐ‘Ð’Ð“` is encoded in hex as D0,90,D0,91,D0,92,D0,93. When interpreted as UTF-8 it gives `АБВГ`. So after getting data from data base you need to convert it from UTF-8 to code page used for displaying.

Comment: @Daniel but it looks wrong in the database. I can't use sorting in my queries.

Comment: You have unpaired conversions `[input]-->{convert to UTF-8}-->[DB]-->[output]` or `[input]-->{convert to UTF-8}-->{convert to UTF-8}-->[DB]-->{convert from UTF-8}-->[output]` and should be `[input]-->{convert to UTF-8}-->[DB]-->{convert from UTF-8}-->[output]`. Maybe you need to check connecion parameters or don't convert data before sending to database or viewer uses wrong encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your ODBC DSN connection string to include this: `ConnSettings=SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'UTF8';`